# Evaluation logic in IAM policy across multiple json policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For an IAM policy, let's say there are two policies:

1. A policy with a single statement to allow access.
2. A second policy with a single statement to deny access.

For example:

```
// first document
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3ListRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:group/davidsgroup" }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
// second document
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyS3ListRead",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/david" }
        }
    ]
}
```

How is it determined whether the resource will ultimately be denied to the user if it has conflicting statements? For example, is it by document order? Granularity of principle? Or how is this usually determined when there are **multiple policy documents** that may apply to a given user.

Comment: Note: the `sid` in the second document ("AllowS3ListRead") is misleading.

Comment: @jarmod thanks -- fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the most basic level: explicit deny > explicit allow > implicit deny.

In your example, even though David's IAM group is explicitly allowed to invoke `s3:ListAllMyBuckets`, David's IAM user is explicitly denied that same action. In this case, the explicit deny trumps the explicit allow and David is denied.

For a deeper dive, see [Policy evaluation logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).

Comment: I see, but if I had both statements inside the same policy block but the `allow` was listed after, would that allow it?

Comment: No. The location of a deny or allow is irrelevant. Deny > Allow, regardless of location.

Comment: by the way, is that a common way to do access policies? I'm more used to I'd say the "SQL way" where you either `GRANT` or `REVOKE` and it's just first-in-first-out (obviously).

Comment: It's security in depth. For example, a resource owner (e.g. of an S3 bucket) has the ability to deny access to any and all resource consumers (e.g. IAM principals), even those that have been explicitly allowed access. The former control acts to prevent mistakes or attempts at privilege escalation in the latter, for example.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Is the AWS IAM modeled on any prior standard/technology, or was it basically just created from scratch?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the origins of IAM.